# An error in the short form of a two-dimensional array?

Tags: front-end, list-manipulation

I noticed very strange behavior in the function Short when applied to a two-dimensional list of real numbers in Mathematica 12.3.  Consider that

```
tmp = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, 48];

Short[tmp]
```

yields

```
{{0.296109, 0.298172}, <<46>>, {0.954461, <<19>>}}
```

But this answer of `{{0.296109,0.298172},<<46>>,{0.954461,<<19>>}}` would seem to be wrong. In particular, the second element of the last item should simply be 0.623015 rather than <<19>>.  Does anyone have some insight into what is happening here?  It is very counter-intuitive to me — seems like some kind of front-end bug.

Comment: Interestingly, the problem sometimes goes away if you use the second argument of Short, i..e, Short[tmp, 2] or Short[tmp, 3] work as expected, but it remains for Short[tmp, 1]

Comment: It also works properly if you remove the semicolon at the end of the definition of tmp.

Comment: @Jean-Pierre What do you get, which you say is proper? I get one of two things, the same two alternatives irrespective of whether I include a semicolon or not:  Either `... <<1>>}` or `... {<<1>>}}`. The latter is wrong, since the last element of the list is a list of two elements, not one. -- Update: Further trials and I got something new (also wrong): `{<<1>>}` (the whole output).

Comment: Works o.k. in version 13.0.1

Comment: @MichaelE2 I just tried a couple of time yeterday with the semicolon removed and got the expected result ```{{..., ...}, <<46>>,{...,...}}```. But repeating many times today, I see that the problem mentionned also comes up often.

Comment: Note that <<19>> is the short version of the real number that should appear there. The full string is 19 characters long (including the backtick at the end).

Comment: @Jean-Pierre Thanks. I found it surprising that the result seems to vary over trials, even on the same system. -- I agree with you about the `<<19>>`. The form shown in the OP seems to conform to an expected form of output. -- I think that might explain the variation that we see. Since the numbers are random and a number strictly between, say, `0.10` and `0.01` has an extra leading zero to display than one between `1.0` and `0.1`, the length of the output changes with each trial.

Comment: @Jean-Pierre Ok, I see.  Thanks for that observation that the <<19>> corresponds to the number of display characters in a real number in Mathematica.  You are almost certainly right but is that how Short is supposed to behave?  It seems not, because had the final element been a list of 19 real numbers rather than a single real number, the very same Short form would have been produced, it would seem.  Why use Short if not to get a compact picture of the structure of a Mathematica expression?

Comment: @DanielHuber Do you get <<19>> as the last element or a real number?

Comment: Last element: `{0.964698, 0.910818}` not <<19>>

Comment: Things can get even wierder: ```{{0.325912,0.21628},<<21>>,{0.575501,<<19>>,<<11>>,<<19>>}}```. This is the result of Short on a list made up of 22 sublists of length 2, followed by a single sublist of length 14. We see that the last sublist uses <<19>> again to represent characters in the real, but the <<11>> in the middle no longer represents characters, but 11 real numbers.

Comment: @DanielHuber  Daniel Huber’s output above shows it is some kind of bug as Mathematica 13 produces the expected result.

Comment: @Jean-Pierre A thought on skeletonized numbers like <<19>> showing up in place of machine real numbers in the output of Short: even if <<19>> or <<20>> or such represented the length of the internal form of a machine number, this still constitutes an error as the short form of a real machine number in Mathematica is its DisplayForm and not this skeletonized integer, it would seem. (Someone please correct me if I am wrong.)